# Calling a text/x-kendo-template script type from a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-scheduler, kendo-template

I have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDjd3.png) new button and on `onclick` event I'm calling function  `openEditor()`, and inside this function I want to call a `text/x-kendo-template` script type. How can I do this?

My code right now:

**Custom button**:

```
schedulerToolbar.append(
"<ul class='k-reset'>
   <li class='k-state-default'>
     <a role='button' href='#' class='k-link newMeetingButton' onclick='openEditor()'>
       Nova reserva
     </a>
   </li>
 </ul>"
)
```

**Function openEditor()**:

```
function openEditor() {
   *code to call customEditorTemplateBh script*
}
```

**Template script**:

```
<script id="customEditorTemplateBh" type="text/x-kendo-template"> 
   *template code*
</script>
```

edit: I'm using a kendo scheduler and I've added that custom button on toolbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code was enough:

```
var scheduler = $("#scheduler-bh").data("kendoScheduler");
scheduler.addEvent({ });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access this by using `kendo.template()` supplying the selected `id` reference to your template, in your case:

```
var template = kendo.template($("#customEditorTemplateBh").html());
```

From here you can supply any required data for your template by calling `template` as a function:

```
var data = {Attribute1: "Test", Attribute2: Test2};

var result = template(data);
```

And finally, update your view by setting the `html` of whatever `<div>` you are using to the result:

```
$("#nameOfYourDivHere").html(result);
```

Reference material for templates can be found [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview#handle-external-templates-and-expressions).